# Kafka Consumer outbound Decreases as Inbound to the topic Increases

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am seeing an issue in my Kafka Consumer, where I see that the throughput of the Consumer is affected when there is a high load from the producer. I see that the throughput goes upto 600K per min when the Producer load is low, but the throughput decreases to around 350K when the Producer load is high, which is causing high Lags in Kafka topic. Is this a discrepancy and Is there anything I can do in the Consumer Implementation? Below is the Consumer config

I have implemented Kafka Consumer using Spring-Kafka

```
key.deserializer : StringDeserializer
value.deserializer : [CUSTOM DESERIALIZER]
enable.auto.commit  : false
max.poll.records : 5
group.id : [MY GROUP]
partition.assignment.strategy : StickyAssignor
max.partition.fetch.bytes : 1048576
bootstrap.servers : [SERVERS]
auto.commit.interval.ms : 3000
auto.offset.reset : latest


factory.setConcurrency(3);


@KafkaListener(topics = "#{kafkaTopicConfig.getStoreSupply()}", containerFactory = EI_LISTNER_FACTORY)

//EI_LISTNER_FACTORY is a Bean..

@Bean(EI_LISTNER_FACTORY)
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, AggQuantityByPrimeValue> eiKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

    Boolean eiCnsumerStartup = [START_UP From Configuration]

    Integer concurrentThreadCount = 3;

    Map<String, Object> config = [properties from ABOVE]
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, AggQuantityByPrimeValue> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config));
    factory.setAutoStartup(eiConsumerStartup);

    if (config.get(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG).equals("false")) {
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.setConcurrency(concurrentThreadCount);
    }
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: We don't recommend `enable.auto.commit=true` - it's better to let the container do the commits in a more deterministic fashion (`BATCH or RECORD AckMode`). Have you tried increasing the `max.poll.records`? 5 is rather low.

Comment: enable.auto.commit is false, Yes I have.. I didn't find any improvement. The thing is, I see that the consumer throughput is fine if the Producer is producing the messages at the lower rate.. not sure whats the connection here.

Comment: Sorry - I didn't see the property. I have no more ideas; sorry. Maybe you need more partitions and consumer instances? Also check the CPU usage on the broker servers.